# Weird behavior with === operator

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I was reading [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html).

and it gave this piece of code saying it prints `false` and `true`.

```
var a:uint = 13;
var b:Number = 13;
trace(a===b); // false
var c:uint = 22;
var d:uint = 22;
trace(c===d); // true
```

But when I run it prints `true` and `true` o.o whats going on?

Answer (score 3):

That would be the expected behavior according to [ActionScript documentation on === operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#strict_equality):

> Numbers and Boolean values are compared by value and are considered
>   equal if they have the same value.